# Set Value in Datagride for dynamic column

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a `datagrid` and its some columns are dynamic I want to set value on those dynamic column

`datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex].column_name` // and I want to change this column name dynamically .

I have column_name value in a another string for example 
some it's may be salary and some time its may be age . I have anything in place of column_name so its should be like :

```
datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex].salary  OR
datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex].age or   
datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex].etc
```

How can I set it ?

Comment: Bracket notation. i.e. `datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex]["salary"]` and `datagride.dataProvider[RowIndex]["age"]`.

Comment: "salary" and "age" are dynamic some times I have salary and same times age  @DodgerThud

Comment: Then you can use `hasOwnProperty("yourpropertyname")` to check beforehand if the property exists.